Error creating bean with name 'editAction' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml] If anyone has time revise all

Exception occurred during processing request: Unable to instantiate Action, editAction,  defined for 'formUpdate' in namespace '/'Error creating bean with name 'editAction' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext-edit.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'editService' of bean class [org.apache.struts.edit.action.EditAction]: Bean property 'editService' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
com.opensymphony.xwork2.XWorkException: Unable to instantiate Action, editAction,  defined for 'formUpdate' in namespace '/'Error creating bean with name 'editAction' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext-edit.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'editService' of bean class [org.apache.struts.edit.action.EditAction]: Bean property 'editService' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?


Error creating bean with name 'editAction' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext-edit.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'editService' of bean class [org.apache.struts.edit.action.EditAction]: Bean property 'editService' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?


Invalid property 'editService' of bean class [org.apache.struts.edit.action.EditAction]: Bean property 'editService' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?


Post the code for EditAction.


Invalid property 'editService' of bean class [org.apache.struts.edit.action.EditAction]: Bean property 'editService' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

So you need to add setter and getter to the bean property editService. You can do it manually or use Lombok annotations. For example
@Getter @Setter
private EditService editService;

